# How to learn EXTJS from basic to advance?

Tags: extjs

Basically i am new to Ext JS framework. always tried to learn from basic. is any website is preferable for to learn from basic to advance?.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also for your answer use this links.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs/  http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs/Introduction

Comment: How about "Learning by doing"? That's how I became proficient.

Comment: Exactly That is a universal way of learning. Also SOF is great place to learn by solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

try this links, try more examples to understand

1) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs
2) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2